# Mapbox Static API - How to use custom markers in GeoJSON overlay?

Tags: mapbox

The [docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/static-images/) say it's possible so I'm obviously missing something. So far I've tested different variations of marker-url and url- in the Mapbox [playground](https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/static/) with both single point and feature collections (as shown in the examples) but all I'm getting are the generic markers.

Any guidance to point me in the right direction?

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/geojson({"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"url-":"http%253A%252F%252Fwebsite.com%252Ffiles%252Fmarkers%252Fgreenpin.png"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.2599,37.8098]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"url-":"http%253A%252F%252Fwebsite.com%252Ffiles%252Fmarkers%252Fgreenpin.png"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.2591,37.8062]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"url-":"http%253A%252F%252Fwebsite.com%252Ffiles%252Fmarkers%252Fgreenpin.png"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.2565,37.8063]}}]})/-122.2647,37.8006,12,0/1080x1080@2x?access_token={token}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not reflected in the official documentation, but in order to use a custom marker with a geojson overlay, you can rely on the `marker-url` property for your features.

If you update your request to the API to the following, you should achieve the desired result:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/geojson({"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-url":"http%253A%252F%252Fwebsite.com%252Ffiles%252Fmarkers%252Fgreenpin.png"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.2599,37.8098]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-url":"http%253A%252F%252Fwebsite.com%252Ffiles%252Fmarkers%252Fgreenpin.png"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.2591,37.8062]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-url":"http%253A%252F%252Fwebsite.com%252Ffiles%252Fmarkers%252Fgreenpin.png"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.2565,37.8063]}}]})/-122.2647,37.8006,12,0/1080x1080@2x?access_token={token}
```

---

Disclaimer: I currently work at Mapbox